# iOS push notifications not showing up through Parse local server

Tags: parse-platform, react-native

I'm doing whatever i can to send ios push notifications to a react-native app and for that app to display notifications.

I've been trying to figure this out for months.

I have a local Parse server running with the following config:

```
{
    "appId": "org.reactjs.native.example.ReactZeroNotifications",
    "masterKey": "masterkey",
    "databaseURI": "mongodb://localhost/test",
    "push": {
        "ios": [
          {
            "pfx": "reactnotification-dev.p12",
            "bundleId": "org.reactjs.native.example.ReactZeroNotifications",
            "passphrase": "*",
            "production": false
          },
          {
            "pfx": "reactnotification-prod.p12",
            "bundleId": "org.reactjs.native.example.ReactZeroNotifications",
            "passphrase": "*",
            "production": true
          }
        ]
    }
}
```

I then send a post request to http://localhost:1337/parse/push with the following headers:

```
X-Parse-Application-Id: org.reactjs.native.example.ReactZeroNotifications
X-Parse-Master-Key: masterkey
```

and the following raw JSON data:

```
{"where": {"deviceType": "ios"},"data":{"alert": "hello NOTIFICATIONS!!"}}
```

Meanwhile I have a react-native app running with pushnotification linked as a library and I receive the register event with a token.

However, my notification event never goes off and I never see a notification at the top of my iPhone as I'm trying to accomplish.

(Note: I just want to see a notification on a react-native app... no matter how this is accomplished, I feel as if I could figure out the rest if I can just get it to work once)

As per recommendation i turned on verbose on the parse server and received the following after posting:

```
verbose: sending push to 0 installations
verbose: sent push!
0 success, 0 failures
```

Comment: Do you get any log ? can you please run parse-server with VERBOSE=1 ?

Comment: verbose: sending push to 0 installations
verbose: sent push! 0 success, 0 failures

hmmm, none of the tutorials i read mentioned "installations"

Comment: in order to send a push you need to query the installation class because the Installation class contains the device token and when you send a push you must send to device token (which is there in order to identify the device) under installation class you can also store the user and then query the Installation where it equal to the user. More info and guide can be found here: http://parseplatform.github.io/docs/android/guide/#push-notifications

Comment: with parse-server you can only send push from cloud code and using Master key, also remove production or development config from the parse server config... it will always try to send pushes with both configs and every time one of them return error... I am using parse-server in production and it works great but pushes are very bad, they even restart your server when they run to some error...

Comment: ok it sounds like I need to subscribe with my device token somehow...

I'll google for more documentation. Hassid, you linked me a very generic large guide on Android push notifications, there is a lot in that guide that doesn't apply to me, so unfortunately I don't think I can use that link. The verbose flag has gotten me closer though! Thank you!!

Comment: I tried following this: http://parseplatform.github.io/docs/rest/guide/#push-notification and posted to "http://localhost:1337/1/installations"
and I get "Cannot POST /1/installations" from the parse server

Comment: That link is for the REST API. The iOS SDK should create the installation object when you initialize Parse on the device

Comment: I've been successful with push through cloud code, but you should check you are able to get a message to all installation objects first.

Comment: I'm using react-native on the client, so I don't have access to the parse API.

Comment: @JasonMcCarrell did you managed to solve this issue?

Comment: Is it resolved now? Please let me know I am facing the same issue.